# v8 memory spike (rss) when defining more than 1000 function (does not reproduce when using --jitless)

Tags: node.js, memory-management, v8, jit

I have a simple node app with 1 function that defines 1000+ functions inside it (without running them).
When I call this function (the wrapper) around 200 times the RSS memory of the process spikes from 100MB to 1000MB and immediately goes down. (The memory spike only happens after around 200~ calls, before that all the calls do not cause a memory spike, and all the calls after do not cause a memory spike)

This issue is happening to us in our node server in production, and I was able to reproduce it in a simple node app here:

https://github.com/gileck/node-v8-memory-issue

When I use `--jitless` pr `--no-opt` the issue does not happen (no spikes). but obviously we do not want to remove all the v8 optimizations in production.

This issue must be some kind of a specific v8 optimization, I tried a few other v8 flags but non of them fix the issue (only --jitless and --no-opt fix it)

Anyone knows which v8 optimization could cause this?

**Update:**

We found that `--no-concurrent-recompilation` fix this issue (No memory spikes at all).
but still, we can't explain it.
We are not sure why it happens and which code changes might fix it (without the flag).

As one of the answers suggests, moving all the 1000+ function definitions out of the main function will solve it, but then those functions will not be able to access the context of the main function which is why they are defined inside it.

Imagine that you have a server and you want to handle a request.
Obviously, The request handler is going to run many times as the server gets a lot of requests from the client.
Would you define functions inside the request handler (so you can access the request context in those functions) or define them outside of the request handler and pass the request context as a parameter to all of them? We chose the first option... what do you think?

Comment: What further info do you have so far? Does memory usage grow exponentially for evey function on has a kind of high watermark?

Comment: Thanks! The memory spike only happens after around 200~ calls, before that all the calls do not cause a memory spike, and all the calls after do not cause a memory spike. I updated the questions with more info. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> anyone knows which v8 optimization could cause this?

Load Elimination.

I guess it's fair to say that *any* optimization *could* cause lots of memory consumption in pathological cases (such as: a nearly 14 MB monster of a function as input, wow!), but Load Elimination is what causes it in this particular case.
You can see for yourself when your run with `--turbo-stats` (and optionally `--turbo-filter=foo` to zoom in on just that function).

You can disable Load Elimination if you feel that you must. A preferable approach would probably be to reorganize your code somewhat: defining 2,000 functions is totally fine, but the function defining all these other functions probably doesn't need to be run in a loop long enough until it gets optimized? You'll avoid not only this particular issue, but get better efficiency in general, if you define functions only once each.

There may or may not be room for improving Load Elimination in Turbofan to be more efficient for huge inputs; that's a longer investigation and I'm not sure it's worth it (compared to working on other things that likely show up more frequently in practice).

I do want to emphasize for any future readers of this that disabling optimization(s) is not generally a good rule of thumb for improving performance (or anything else), on the contrary; nor are any other "secret" flags needed to unlock "secret" performance: the default configuration is very carefully optimized to give you what's (usually) best. It's a very rare special case that a particular optimization pass interacts badly with a particular code pattern in an input function.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful information. this example mimics our production server. on each request, we define all those functions and call them. we want the context of the request to be available in all those functions, otherwise, we would need to pass the context of the request as a parameter. what do you think?

we found that `--no-concurrent-recompilation` fix the issue for us. does that hint why the spike happen? I couldn't find any useful info about it in v8 docs.

Comment: The fact that `--no-concurrent-recompilation` appears to have an effect on this is an artifact of your test setup, it doesn't actually change anything. -- I would definitely not redefine 2,000 functions every time the request handler is called. One option might be to use a class instead: `class Handler { constructor(request) { this.request = request; } helper_function_one() { ...this.request... } ... }`. That way, all helpers can access `this.request`, and you only create a `new Handler(request)` for each request, without redefining all its methods.

Comment: I agree that moving to classes is a better option, but it's a big refactor of our code base. we probably made a mistake going to the path of the nested functions to begin with, we did not expect the scale we ended up with. However, if there is something we can do to improve our production stability without a huge refactor, it would be amazing for us. I will try to use `--no-concurrent-recompilation` in production and see how its behaves. can you think of any potential disasters using it in production? can you think of better flags to use? Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Gil Define "disaster". It'll make optimization happen on the main thread instead of in the background. Given that your worry is a slow compilation job, I don't think blocking the main thread for it will be an improvement... You haven't explained why a short peak of ~900 MB memory consumption is so bad, nor have you indicated what kind of peak would be acceptable, so it's hard to assess possible alternatives. I'd get started on that refactoring, maybe it can be done incrementally; every nested function you pull out will help a bit.

Comment: Yes, that's what we will probably do. Thanks a lot of your help!